# Could not autowire in JavaSpring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I don't know why MyModel's simulationContoller cannot be autowired.
And there is a tons of problematic messages appeared.
Could you help me out?

The below code is mostly dependent on JASA(http://jasa.sourceforge.net/)and JABM(http://jabm.sourceforge.net/)and JASA's embeded example which converted to Java code.

You could install it with main class being MyLauncher.java and VM option being 
`-Djabm.config=MyMain.java`in IntelliJ editor.

MyLauncher(main class)

```
package MyMy;

import net.sourceforge.jabm.DesktopSimulationManager;
import net.sourceforge.jabm.SimulationController;
import net.sourceforge.jabm.spring.PropertyOverrideWithReferencesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(ScopeConfig.class);
        context.register(MyMain.class);
        context.refresh();
        final DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory(context);
        final DesktopSimulationManager manager = new DesktopSimulationManager() {
            @Override
            public SimulationController getSimulationController() {
                return (SimulationController) simulationController.getSimulation();
            }

            @Override
            protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
                URL imgURL = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("net/sourceforge/jabm/" + path);
                if (imgURL != null) {
                    return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find file: " + path);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void runSingleExperiment() {
                if (this.simulationProperties != null) {
                    PropertyOverrideConfigurer configurer = new PropertyOverrideWithReferencesConfigurer();
                    configurer.setProperties(simulationProperties);
                    configurer.postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
                }
                launch((SimulationController) beanFactory.getBean("simulationController"));
            }
        };
        manager.initialise();
    }
}
```

MyMain

```
package MyMy;

import net.sourceforge.jabm.SpringSimulationController;
import net.sourceforge.jabm.report.Report;
import net.sourceforge.jabm.util.MutableStringWrapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MyMain {
    @Bean
    public SpringSimulationController simulationController(Report priceTimeSeriesChart,
                                                           Report currentPriceTimeSeriesChart,
                                                           Report equilibriumPriceTimeSeriesChart,
                                                           Report currentPriceCSVReport) {
        SpringSimulationController ret = new SpringSimulationController();
        ret.setSimulationBeanName("marketSimulation");
        ret.setNumSimulations(10);
        ret.setReports(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(priceTimeSeriesChart, currentPriceTimeSeriesChart, equilibriumPriceTimeSeriesChart, currentPriceCSVReport)));
        ret.setModelDescription("Iori and Chiarella - A Simulation analysis of a the microstructure of double auction markets");
        return ret;
    }

MyModel

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;

@Repository
@Configuration
public class MyModel {
    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    MarketSimulation marketSimulation(@Lazy SimulationController simulationController,
                                      @Lazy Population evolvingPopulation,
                                      AgentMixer randomArrivalAgentMixer,
                                      @Lazy AgentInitialiser agentInitialiserProxy,
                                      Auctioneer cda) {
        MarketSimulation ret = new MarketSimulation();
        ret.setSimulationController(simulationController);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public TimePriorityPricingPolicy timePriorityPricing() {
        return new TimePriorityPricingPolicy();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public ContinuousDoubleAuctioneer cda(TimePriorityPricingPolicy pricingPolicy) {
        ContinuousDoubleAuctioneer ret = new ContinuousDoubleAuctioneer();
        ret.setPricingPolicy(pricingPolicy);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public RandomArrivalAgentMixer randomArrivalAgentMixer(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        RandomArrivalAgentMixer ret = new RandomArrivalAgentMixer(prng);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public ProxyFactoryBean agentInitialiserProxy() {
        LazyInitTargetSource src = new LazyInitTargetSource();
        src.setTargetBeanName("agentInitialiser");
        ProxyFactoryBean ret = new ProxyFactoryBean();
        ret.setTargetSource(src);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public MarketAgentInitialiser agentInitialiser(MarketSimulation marketSimulation) {
        MarketAgentInitialiser ret = new MarketAgentInitialiser();
        ret.setMarket(marketSimulation);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public MersenneTwister64 prng() {
        return new MersenneTwister64(new Date());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public AgentList chartists(ObjectFactory<Agent> chartistFactory) {
        AgentList ret = new AgentList();
        ret.setAgentFactory(chartistFactory);
        ret.populateFromFactory();
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean chartistFactory() {
        ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean ret = new ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean();
        ret.setTargetBeanName("chartistPrototype");
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public SimpleTradingAgent chartistPrototype(SimpleMarkupStrategy returnForecastStrategy,
                                                ReturnForecastValuationPolicy chartistValuationPolicy) {
        SimpleTradingAgent ret = new SimpleTradingAgent();
        ret.setStrategy(returnForecastStrategy);
        ret.setValuationPolicy(chartistValuationPolicy);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public SimpleMarkupStrategy returnForecastStrategy(SimulationController simulationController,
                                                       UniformDistribution markupDistribution,
                                                       ForecastTradeDirectionPolicy tradeDirectionPolicy,
                                                       MersenneTwister64 prng) {
         SimpleMarkupStrategy ret = new SimpleMarkupStrategy();
        ret.setScheduler(simulationController);
        ret.setMarkupDistribution(markupDistribution);
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        ret.setTradeDirectionPolicy(tradeDirectionPolicy);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public ForecastTradeDirectionPolicy tradeDirectionPolicy(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        ForecastTradeDirectionPolicy ret = new ForecastTradeDirectionPolicy();
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public UniformDistribution markupDistribution(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        UniformDistribution ret = new UniformDistribution();
        ret.setMax(0.5);
        ret.setMin(0.);
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public MutableDoubleWrapper gbmFundamentalPrice() {
        MutableDoubleWrapper ret = new MutableDoubleWrapper();
        ret.setValue(500.);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public GeometricBrownianMotionPriceProcess gbmPriceProcess(MutableDoubleWrapper gbmFundamentalPrice,
                                                               MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        GeometricBrownianMotionPriceProcess ret = new GeometricBrownianMotionPriceProcess();
        ret.setPriceWrapper(gbmFundamentalPrice);
        ret.setDrift(0.2);
        ret.setVolatility(0.4);
        ret.setDt(0.00005);
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ReturnForecastValuationPolicy chartistValuationPolicy(ChartistForecaster chartistForecaster) {
        ReturnForecastValuationPolicy ret = new ReturnForecastValuationPolicy();
        ret.setForecaster(chartistForecaster);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public ChartistForecaster chartistForecaster(final MarketSimulation mark,
                                                 UniformDistribution chartistWindowSizeDistribution) {
        class _internal extends  ChartistForecaster {
            private _internal() {
                this.market = mark;
            }
        }
        ChartistForecaster ret = new _internal();
        ret.setWindowSizeDistribution(chartistWindowSizeDistribution);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public UniformDistribution chartistWindowSizeDistribution(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        UniformDistribution ret = new UniformDistribution();
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public EvolvingPopulation evolvingPopulation(AgentList agentList,
                                                 MersenneTwister64 prng,
                                                 CombiBreeder uniformBreeder) {
        EvolvingPopulation ret = new EvolvingPopulation();
        ret.setAgentList(agentList);
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        ret.setBreeder(uniformBreeder);
        ret.setBreedingInterval(1);
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public CombiBreeder uniformBreeder(//Breeder mutationBreeder,
                                       Breeder fitnessProportionateBreeder) {
        CombiBreeder ret = new CombiBreeder();
        ret.setBreedingPipeline(Arrays.asList(//mutationBreeder,
                fitnessProportionateBreeder));
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public MutationBreeder mutationBreeder(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        MutationBreeder ret = new MutationBreeder();
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        ret.setMutationOperator(new WeightMutationOperator());
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("simulation")
    public FitnessProportionateBreeder fitnessProportionateBreeder(MersenneTwister64 prng) {
        FitnessProportionateBreeder ret = new FitnessProportionateBreeder();
        ret.setPrng(prng);
        ret.setFitnessFunction(new ForecastErrorFitnessFunction());
        ret.setImitationOperator(new ValuationPolicyImitationOperator());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jasa_sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasa_sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>jasa_sample</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jasa/jasa -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.jasa</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasa</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Tons of code and no clear problem statement. Please try to come up with a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Henry, I tried to...but the simulation I'm doing seems so intricately wired so I couldn't remove the contents of the file...

Comment: Please provide a problem statement, along with the errors you are receiving and any other relevant information.